# Auto focus the next input field

Tags: javascript, html

How do you auto focus the next input field?

When all the input fields are placed one after the other like this

```
<div>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <input type="number" name="name">
</div>
```

you can generally just do something like this

```
this.nextSibling.nextSibling.focus();
```

However, I have a situation where there is a variable number of `<span>` tags between each input field.

Something like

```
<div>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="name">
</div>
```

How do I configure

```
this.nextSibling.nextSibling.focus();
```

to get to the next input sibling?

Comment: hey why not just use `tabindex`? Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: Because of the nature of my code, I need it to be done automatically.

Comment: thanks for the reply. could you give any specific example or scenario?

Comment: It's like a question and answer system where there are more than one question. If the answer is right then the next input field should be focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just keep looping through the `nextElementSibling`s until you find one that matches the `tagName` you're looking for:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) => {
  input.oninput = function() {
    let { nextElementSibling } = this;
    while (nextElementSibling && nextElementSibling.tagName !== 'INPUT') {
      nextElementSibling = nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
    }
    if (nextElementSibling) {
      nextElementSibling.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="name">
</div>
```

If you want to specify something more specific than a `tagName`, you can use `Element.prototype.matches`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) => {
  input.oninput = function() {
    let { nextElementSibling } = this;
    while (nextElementSibling && !nextElementSibling.matches('input[name="foo"]')) {
      nextElementSibling = nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
    }
    if (nextElementSibling) {
      nextElementSibling.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="foo">
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="foo">
</div>
```

Note the use of `nextElementSibling` rather than `nextSibling` - `nextSibling` will select adjacent *nodes*, not just Elements. (for example, `nextSibling` can evaluate to a text node, which you don't care about.) If you want an element, best to be specific and use `nextElementSibling`.

Comment: `while (nextElementSibling && nextElementSibling.tagName !== 'INPUT')` does the word `INPUT` need to be capitalised?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the `.tagName` property always returns a capitalized string.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
    <input type="number" tabindex="1" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" tabindex="2" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" tabindex="3" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" tabindex="4" name="name">
</div>
```

I am using `tabindex` in this example because your question doesn't provide any insight as to why I can't use it.

Comment: While `tabindex` works when the user wants to *deliberately* focus on the next item, OP wants to *automatically* focus the next item, presumably on some event. Do you know of a way to automatically focus the next tabindex?

Comment: nope, but i think the second part of your answer was what first came to my mind on reading your question..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable and to keep track of current input. And each time increase it. And focus the next input from array of inputs.Below is the code

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let i = 0;
inputs.forEach(inp => inp.oninput = () => inputs[i+1] && inputs[++i].focus())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="name">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" name="name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather simple solution. Use id attribute on the input elements. Then you can automatically move to the next element with a simple switch within your validation function.

Such as:

```
function validateInput(input){
  //Your validation code
  switch(input.id){
    case'input1':
      document.getElementById('input2').focus();
      break;
    case'input2':
      document.getElementById('input3').focus();
      break;
    case'input3':
      document.getElementById('input4').focus();
      break;
  }
}

<input type='number' name='name' id='input1' onchange='validateInput(this)'>
<input type='number' name='name' id='input2' onchange='validateInput(this)'>
```

Then you don't have to worry about where in the document it is, you can always find it. You could even do your validation from within the switch or send it to an external function and continue within validateInput with a non-null return

Comment: This is probably as straight forward as it gets. However I may have up to about 20 input fields and so I didn't want to account for them separately :)